# Is there a way to ignore mute/silent crashes in firebase crashylytics stats?

Tags: crashlytics

Firebase crashlytics has an option to mute crashes that we think are not valid or going to be fixed by third party libraries. But i think those crashes are still taken into account when calculating stats like crash free percentages. Is there a way to mark a crash such that its totally ignored or thrown away and not taken into consideration for any of those stats calculations?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The reason is that when there is a crash, the Crashlytics SDK will let the Analytics SDK know about the crash. From there, Analytics will file this as an "app_exception".

The Crash Free Users information is collected and reported by Analytics and not by Crashlytics and is bases on the "app_exception" events.

This is described in this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/troubleshooting?platform=ios#cfu-calculation).