# How do i remove a device from firebase crashlytics?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Is there a filter available to remove a specific device or a specific Crash from firebase crashlytics?
I have been getting a crash and i want Firebase to ignore it, From the list as well as the Analyitcs above.

[[image: Attached Image for reference!]]

Hoping for help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to close or mute selected issues, you can use one of this options depending on what you need. Then, when using the filter `Issue state = "Open"` those won't show up in the list. Check this screenshot:

[image]

However, this will affect only the issue list, it doesn't affect the stats. Especially the `Crash-Free Users` because this information comes from Analytics and not from Crashlytics. Check this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74468880) for reference.